# Woocommerce: Get the chosen attribute from item in cart

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

In the cart, i get a variation_id for all my variable products.

Is it possible to get the choosen attribute from that id in any way?

I have tried:

```
<?php $variation = new WC_Product_Variation($cart_item[variation_id]);?>

<?php foreach($variation->get_variation_attributes() as $name => $attr): ?>
    <?php $name = substr($name, 10); //remove attribute_ from the key. ?>

    <?php echo $variation->get_attribute($name); ?>

<?php endforeach; ?>
```

but that only outputs ALL available attributes for that variation, not the chosen one.

It feels like i am missing something obvious here, so any pointes in the correct direction would be lovely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking and looking I found another method in the WC_Product_Variation class.

**get_variation_attributes()**

It does exactly what I want.

For more information, look here: 
http://docs.woothemes.com/wc-apidocs/source-class-WC_Product_Variation.html#263-270